# How to access a form component with a thread?

Tags: c#

Simple question, I **had an application in console mode**. Every thing would write in the console using `Console.WriteLine`. However, **now I have a form** and a listbox. I know easily how to do it, however, what is the **proper way** to do it?

Comment: Proper way to do WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the UI from another thread using delegate, simple and neat:

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                textBox1.Value = "your text";
            });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer. Can you tell me where I go wrong? Here is my code : this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                                        lstStatus.Items.Add("test");
                                    });